# Bar chart or histogram of grouped values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

[image]

For a table as above how can I count how many labels have value between [0-2] and [3-5] and with Excel show that as a bar chart or histogram?

Comment: *how can I count..?*: `countif` will do. *... show it as a bar chart or histogram , does excel charts do it?*: Yes they do

Comment: Use a pivot table, you can then pivotchart that.

Comment: The *between [0-2]* and *between [3-5]* will require [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) to set a high and low point.

Comment: @DirkReichel I bet you did not understood my question and can not do that :) look at the answer below and my comment

Comment: just for you: for <=2 use `=COUNTIF([your range],"<=2")` and for the >2 `=COUNTIF([your range],">2")-COUNTIF([your range],">5")`... select this two cells and insert chart... done... now tell what was wrong at my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PivotChart example (`value` in ROWS, `label` in COLUMNS and Sum of value for VALUES):

[image: SO34157579 first example]

Oh! I forgot to mention that the banding [0-2] or [3-5] can be achieved by Group in the PT - select Row labels and start at 0, end at 2, in steps of 2.

For this instead:

[image: SO34157579 second example]

remove `label` from LEGEND(SERIES) (COLUMNS) and use Count of rather than Sum of `value`.

Comment: correct up to here , but I do not need that , I just want to show that :
in the range [0-2] we have 5 elements and in the range [3-5] we have 6 elements ,  the chart with two bars , one bar for 0-2 and one bar for 3-5